# Stored procedure performs differently between 2 different access databases

Tags: vba, ms-access, odbc

I'm hitting my head against a wall and not sure what the cause is.

I have a stored procedure in MySQL that runs perfectly. Returns around 1500 rows. The connection to the database where the sp resides is through odbc.

In a new access database i can call this via bbq and ado, iterate through it, update labels and load a local db. Takes less than 6 seconds which is acceptable.

In another preexisting database i copied the same forms, local table and vba to it. However, in this access database it takes about 3 minutes because it gets hung on the same sp above. It's being called identically.I've even commented out everything on this one that runs at startup thinking there was another clog. I tried opening the form on open as well as via a button with no difference.

I see no apparent differences between them that would cause this. Is there some setting im missing or oblivious to? Things to check? Like i said vba to call the sp is identical between the two.

Comment: do the linked tables work just find in 2nd database? (ie: click on table - it opens fast).

Comment: Yep. Ended up trying a pass through query and it resolved speed issue on slow database. Oddly enough using a pass through on the already fast database didn't change its performance at all.

Answer (score 0):

So i resolved my issue by attempting a pass through query and that brought the performance up significantly to match the faster database.  Anyone coming across something similar def give pass throughs a shot.